# Deploying React App to GitHub Pages: 404 page not found

Tags: reactjs, github

I have been working on a React App for weeks on my local machine. I have a repository of the project on GitHub and I am trying to deploy the app to GitHub Pages so I can have a live version of the project I can share.

I have followed a coupled of tutorials and everything works fine during the set up;However, the link takes me to an empty 404 page.

So far, I have added `gh-pages` as a dependency and ran `npm run deploy and build commands`. I also added the homepage script tag with no issues. After running the commands the site publishes but its not live.

https://silvodesigns.github.io/MemoryGame/

````
  "name": "game",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": " https://silvodesigns.github.io/MemoryGame/",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "pretty-ms": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: Can you share your github repo for the page?

Comment: Thank you! GitHub pages requires you to choose a theme even if you are not using it. After choosing a random Jekil theme now the page is up and running.