# How to deploy a react project found in a subdirectory in the main branch to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, create-react-app, github-pages

## Context

I have a github repository `my-projects` which contains multiple folders each representing a separate web project. The GitHub Pages site for this repository is currently being built from the `main` branch (not `gh-pages` branch) and the Github page has a Github Jekyll theme.

The simplified file structure of the repository is as follows:

```
my-projects/
├─ project1/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ README.md
├─ project2/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ README.md
├─ project3/
│  ├─ README.md
│  ├─ dist/
│  │  ├─ index.html
├─ project4/
│  ├─ README.md
│  ├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ public/
│  ├─ build/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ package-lock.json
│  ├─ src/
├─ config.yml
├─ README.md
```

Some of the projects have the production build in the `dist` folder.
The following links are all working websites deployed by Github Pages:

- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/`
- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project1`
- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project2`
- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project3/dist`

## Issue with deploying react-app `project4`

`project4` folder is a react app which was generated from `create-react-app`.
Here’s the `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "my-projects",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.12",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I generated the production build with `npm run build` and pushed the `build` folder to Github. However after pushing the newly created build folder to github, I am unable to view the website. I tried accessing the following links but had no success:

- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4` : Displays README of `project4` instead of actual project
- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4/build` : Displays a blank page with the following console errors:

```
main.80069716.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.0634878b.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
main.0634878b.css:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://clldacgmdnnanihiibdgemajcfkmfhia/contentScript.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

## What I tried

- I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@isharamalaviarachchi/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-into-github-pages-b2c96292b18e) which uses `gh-pages` branch but unfortunately it still does not work as desired. If I change the Github Pages branch from `main` to `gh-pages` in the repository settings, all my other projects stop working. For example, I error 404 when accessing `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project2`. I had to change the branch back to `main` to get it to work.
- I tried setting homepage in package.json to `.` but got the a blank page with same console errors as before.
- I tried setting homepage in package.json to `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4/build/` but got the a blank page with same console errors as before.

So to summarize, here's what I want to achieve:

- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4` should show the README of `project4`. This already works.
- `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4/build` should show the production build of `project4`. This does not work yet.
- All other websites (for example `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project2`) should still be accessible. With the branch currently set to `main`, this also works.

## References

[React app shows a blank page after deployment to github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978742/react-app-shows-a-blank-page-after-deployment-to-github-pages)

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/478

[Deploying React App to GitHub Pages: 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58149928/deploying-react-app-to-github-pages-404-page-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with the following steps:

1. Set `"homepage"` in `package.json` file to `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4/build`.
2. `cd project4` and update production build with `npm run build`.
3. `git push` : Push updated production build and `package.json` file to `main` branch on Github.

The deployed website will be found at `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4/build` and the README will be accessible at `http://username.github.io/my-projects/project4`. All other projects are still accessible at their respective links.